# css messes up on different resolution

Tags: html, css

[image]While developing, lets say i declared the following css properties

```
.buttons-pos {
    /*margin: 0px 20px;*/
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:20px;
    position: relative;
    right:-550px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 3px;

}
```

css for two blue buttons:

```
  .checksheet {
    /*margin: 0px 20px;*/
    left: 400px;
    top: 45px;
    position: relative;

}
  .nchecksheet {
    /*margin: 0px 20px;*/
    left: 680px;
    top:2px;
    position: relative;

}
```

This looks perfectly fine in my computer but when i check at other computers.. the position is all messed up?

What is a way to solve this issue?

Attached screen shot.
Ignore the gray bar...for now..

The blue buttons you see.. 
That is the in the center of screen in my laptop..

But here.. it has shifted to left.

If I look this in my laptop..
The blue buttons will be in the center of my screen
but the gray bar will be shifted on right..

Comment: are you looking at it on these other computers using the same browser?

Comment: what exactly does "all messed up mean"? is it just the button's position that's messed up? Can you provide a screen grab of the problem in action?

Comment: position: relative; is used twice.. not sure if this is the problem. Can you give more markup? Maybe there are some floating elements in your page which could mess things up if the other computers have different resolution?

Comment: First of all, there are two duplicate `position:relative` values. Second, because it is `display:inline-block` and includes padding, if the browser size is smaller, it may move onto a new line because it can't fit in the previous. This means if you're working in a higher resolution screen and move to a lower-res screen, problems like this are likely to occur. Solution: make the container a huge width, or make the button `position: absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: duplicate rules won't cause a problem, whatever the last value is will be applied.

Comment: @ultranaut: Just a note. I made edits, see above.

Comment: Hi.. Please see added css as well

Comment: Have you tried putting a div around the buttons with `margin:0 auto;`?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing a little bit more of the markup and styles, but I would bet money that the `right: -550px;` in combination with your screen resolution and browser window size is your "culprit". Does the problem appear/disappear depending on how you size the browser window?

Comment: @ultranaut: yepp.. it doesnt moves from its position.. it just stays there...

Comment: @ultranaut: how do i fix it.. :(

Comment: We can't really answer that without seeing the relevant html in addition to the css and knowing what exactly it is that you want it to do. Context is the thing here.

Comment: @ultranaut: Al i want is to show these buttons on the site.. properly.. thats it..

Comment: Seriously not trying to be a dick, but "properly" isn't a spec.

Comment: @ultranaut: hahaha .. maybe i can convey the same ;)

Comment: try putting this in jsfiddle that way we can see how you want it

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go through your code in depth, but your problem is almost certainly because of hardcoding the positions and dimensions in pixels. When you design on a higher resolution device and later check on lower resolutions devices, you'll find that your layout is messed up.

You should probably use [percentages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/percentage) in laying out your page if you want it to be fluid.

Another solution, which might suit your needs better is designing for the lowest common denominator. This essentially means, in this case, that you decide what the lowest resolution your page will be displayed on is, and then design for that resolution, centering the page for other resolutions.